# How to change font-size of dev-tools without zooming the web page itself

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, font-size

You can increase/decrease font size within chrome's developer toolbox by pressing `CMD` and `+` or `-` but it seems only to work in docked mode.

If I do that within an undocked separate window, it zooms in/out the web page too.

Is there a possibility to achieve the same in floating-window-mode?

**EDIT:** See related bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1100135

Comment: It works correctly here in Windows both with docked/floating mode. The only problem is that the page contents "jumps" in undocked mode (this is a bug in Chrome) but the font stays the same.

Comment: thank you, font stays the same but the zoom factor is changing and my font-size is depended on the zoom factor,..

Comment: In my case nothing changes at all on several sites I've tried.

Comment: Ok, thank you @wOxxOm, that's a company notebook; I don't know what is exactly going on here,..

Comment: I've reported the related bug I've seen https://crbug.com/1100135